# Looking for a shell command to read non-binary part of most common image types

Tags: php, hacking, find, grep, pictures

A website I'm hosting on my dedicated server has been hacked.
Some pictures have been infected with things like `<?php eval(base64_decode(....));?>`.
I'm looking for a generic shell command which would able to read the headers of the most common image types (jpg, gif, tiff, etc.).

I tried **jhead** and others, jut jhead can only read EXIF data from JPG.

The aim is to find all infected images like this :

```
find -type f \( -iname "*jpg" -or -iname "*.jpeg" -or ... \) -exec sh -c 'magicimgheadersdisplay "{}" | grep eval" \;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep -l` can be used to report infected files.  Try a command like

```
find -type f \( -iname "*jpg" -or -iname "*.jpeg" -or ... \) -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l '<?php eval(base64_decode'
```

The `-print0` and `-0` arguments allow filenames and paths to contain spaces.

Comment: THank you very much. It's what I wanted! I succeeded to build my final command with your answer : `view -M "+set grepprg=grep\ -an\ \$*\ /dev/null" "+call setqflist([])" "+silent! bufdo silent! grepadd! eval %" "+cw" $(find -type f \( -iname "*.jpg" -or -iname "*.jpeg" -or -iname "*.gif" -or -iname "*.tiff" -or -iname "*.png" \) -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l 'eval')`

Answer (score 2):

`strings` will display any printable bits it finds in a file. From there you can feed it into `grep` to find text within.